# Multiplas referencias a um FK na mesma coluna/linha

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Boa tarde colegas, gostaria de um auxilio para modelar um BD, a duvida é o seguinte:

É possivel eu ter mais de um ID de FK em uma tupla? EX:

```sql
tabela teste1

|id_teste1|id_teste2|teste|teste01|
| 1       |1,2,3    |tes  | les   |



tabela teste2

|id_teste2|registro1|registro2|
|1        |lalala   |lelele   |
|2        |bababa   |bebebe   |
|3        |cacaca   |cecece   |
```

No momento de realizar a consulta, eu conseguiria visualizar os dados
ta tabela teste2?

mais ou menos desta maneira

Alguma sugestão de de como eu poderia ter tal resultado?
mais ou menos desta maneira:

```sql
|id_teste1|registro1|registro2|teste|teste01|
| 1       |lalala   |lelele   |tes  | les   |
| 1       |bababa   |bebebe   |tes  | les   |    
| 1       |cacaca   |cecece   |tes  | les   |
```

Para não ficar fora de contexto vou explicar o que estou tentando fazer,
é uma ferramenta para ler uma planilha e gravar os dados em um BD, só que as
linhas de algumas áreas podem variar, minha ideia era fazer uma tabela a parte,
e cada linha da planilha seria um registro, e todos esses registro, seriam referenciados no registro da tabela "superior", como se a tabela "planilha"
tivesse uma coluna onde eu posso ter os ids dos registros como pk, como no exemplo acima "id_teste2" onde temos 3 referencias.

Tenho experiencia limitada em sql e gostaria da sugestão dos senhores colegas ;D

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

*ps: eu pesquisei um bucado e não tive resultados D:

edit:

A relação é: N resgistros ta tabela `teste2` para cada(1) registro da tabela `teste1` ; D

Comment: A relação entre a tabela `teste2` e a tabela `teste1` é de 1-n? Se sim, o ideal seria ter uma tupla pra cada registro da tabela referenciada, no caso, 3 itens na `teste1`

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves, a relação seria ao contrario acredito eu, varios registros na `teste2` para um registro da `teste1`, obrigado pela resposta Ronaldo ; D

Comment: Em uma base de dados devidamente normalizada isto não é possível pois um atributo não atômico viola as regras de normalização. Agora existem SGBD que permitem implementar tal tipo de solução, mas será uma implementação particular e fora do padrão SQL.

Comment: Pois é @anonimo, eu verifiquei as regras de normalização e vi que fugia do padrão, se eu te contasse como estava o primeiro modelo, os DBA de plantão já me matava kkk, a proposito, muito obrigado pela resposta ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os relacionamentos de tabelas podem ser:

**- 1-1**

Ex: uma tabela de usuários e uma de clientes, onde cada cliente pode ter UM usuário, e cada usuário pode pertencer a UM cliente apenas

**- 1-n**

Ex: uma tabela de pedidos e uma de pedido_itens, onde cada pedido pode ter N itens, mas cada item pode pertencer a UM pedido apenas

**- n-n**

Ex: uma tabela de alunos e uma tabela de aula, onde um aluno pode ter N aulas, e cada aula pode ter N alunos

---

O modelo que vc deseja é 1-n (me corrija se eu tiver entendido errado a pergunta).

Nesse caso, a tabela `teste1` equivale ao pedido, e a `teste2` equivale aos itens.

O modelo está correto: sua tabela `teste1` possui um `id_teste2` que referencia o item da `teste2`.
Mas pra cada "item de pedido" (teste1) vc precisará ter um registro, onde todos esses itens teriam o mesmo id_teste2.

**Exemplo:**

Considerando os modelos:

```
teste1

id_teste1 | id_teste2 | item    | quantidade
----------+-----------+---------+--------------
1         | 1         | mouse   | 2
2         | 1         | teclado | 1
```

```
teste2

id_teste2 | numeroPedido
----------+-------------
1         | 5001
```

Essa consulta:

```sql
select *
from teste2 t2
inner join teste1 t1
on t1.id_teste2 = t2.id_teste2
```

retornaria esses dados:

```
id_teste2 | numeroPedido | id_teste1 | id_teste2 | item    | quantidade |
1         | 5001         | 1         | 1         | mouse   | 2          |
1         | 5001         | 2         | 1         | teclado | 1          |
```

Comment: Entendi Ronaldo, você poderia exemplificar uma consulta neste caso por gentileza?

Então o PK do `teste2` não pode ser unique, né? assim a cada registro da tabela `teste1` teremos diversos registros com o mesmo `id_teste2`, no momento de consultar eu passo a referencia do `id_teste2` e consigo visualizar todos os registros eu tenham o `id_teste2` referenciado né?

Comment: Outro ponto, eu não poderia deixar como autoincrement também né?, e o durante o insert eu teria que passar manualmente os ids para eles serem iguais depois correto?

Comment: Muito obrigado Ronaldo, marcado como resposta ; D

Comment: O campo FK da tabela "dependente" NÃO pode ser autoincrement. E toda FK tem que referenciar uma PK de outra tabela, que na maioria dos casos é autoincremento.

Comment: Respondendo seu primeiro comentário: é isso mesmo :)

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado mesmo Ronaldo, tenha um ótimo dia ; D